# html doesnt render in partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, d3.js

Following is the code that i am using to render a html view.
    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $("#divChart").load('http://localhost/abcd.Portal/BarChart.html');
    });
</script>


<div style="width: 100%;" id="divChart"></div>
```

HTML that I am trying to load

```
<style>
    .bar {
        fill: steelblue;
    }

        .bar:hover {
            fill: brown;
        }

    .axis {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

    .x.axis path {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<body>

    <script>
        debugger;
        var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(10, "%");

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/abcd.Portal/Dashboard/GetData',
            type: 'GET',
            data: '',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'text',
            async: true,
            error: function (xhr) {
                //alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                result = eval(JSON.parse(result));

                x.domain(result.map(function (d) { return d.letter; }));
                y.domain([0, d3.max(result, function (d) { return d.frequency; })]);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis)
                  .append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", ".71em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Frequency");

                svg.selectAll(".bar")
                    .data(result)
                  .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "bar")
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.letter); })
                    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.frequency); })
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
            }
        });

        function type(d) {
            d.frequency = +d.frequency;
            return d;
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

I get no errors but my view is not rendering. I am trying to render a d3 bar chart. Any suggestion where I am going wrong.

I have a parent which loads my partial view. Now if i write the html code inside the partial i view it gives error. So, I tried loading the html file instead.

Comment: can u set a temporary fixed height for the div and see if the height is the cause of not showing anything, no error at all? Have you check your console if the call is success and it did return a response from the server

Comment: @Se0ng11 No errors at all

Comment: is the debugger getting hit?

Comment: @ta-run : Yes... all getting debugged properly, just noting is getting rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to load partial view using jquery, use an action for it.

Create an action which will return the partial view:

```
public ActionResult BarChart()
{
  return View();
}
```

and in jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $("#divChart").load('@Url.Action("BarChart","ControllerName")');
    });
```

Comment: :Actually the partial view has a parent. Can i make partial view as a parent of some other action.?

Comment: I have a parent which loads my partial view. Now if i write the html code inside the partial i view it gives error. So, I tried loading the html file instead.

Comment: i don't think you can do like that action should be called and then respective view to be rendered